# ztree - use-package key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, use-package

I tried to set key bindings to ztree (dir and diff), but they are not working after the emacs startup (there is no errors). `f8` and `C-f8` works but not the navigation keys. Pleas help.

When I eval my init.el after starting ztree all keys are working correctly.
My init:

```
(use-package ztree
  :bind (("<f8>"   . ztree-dir)
         ("C-<f8>" . ztree-diff)
         :map ztree-mode-map
         ("n" . next-line)
         ("p" . previous-line)
         :map ztreedir-mode-map
         ("f" . ztree-dir-narrow-to-dir)
         ("b" . ztree-dir-widen-to-parent)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, now I use:

```
;; to bind keys to primary commands within ztree module
(use-package ztree
  :bind (("<f8>"   . ztree-dir)
         ("C-<f8>" . ztree-diff)))

;; to bind keys to local keymaps within ztree-dir
(use-package ztree-dir
  :bind (:map ztreedir-mode-map
              ("f" . ztree-dir-narrow-to-dir)
              ("b" . ztree-dir-widen-to-parent)))

;; to bind keys to local keymaps within ztree-dir and ztree-diff
(use-package ztree-view
  :bind (:map ztree-mode-map
              ("n" . next-line)
              ("p" . previous-line)))
```